# Por que um código com erro não executa as partes sem erro?

Tags: javascript, compilação

```js
console.log(a);
console.log('still going...');
```

O código acima é um exemplo do site do [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#Description), o exemplo acima tenta mostrar o valor da variável `a`, mas a variável `a` não foi definida, assim é retornado um erro no *console* do navegador:

> ```
> Uncaught ReferenceError: a is not defined
> at <anonymous>:1:13
> ```

Só que o problema é que o código abaixo:

```
console.log('still going...');
```

Não possui nenhum tipo de erro, porque ele não foi executado?

Comment: Teste isso para vc ver `window.onload = function() {
  document.body.style.background = 'red';
  console.log(a);
};

console.log('still going...');` Coloca o erro dentro de um escopo...

Comment: Então não é regra que algum erro de código pare de funcionar o restante @hugocsl.? principalmente em `Javascript`.

Comment: @VirgilioNovic depende da situação, dei o exemplo apenas de forma didática, se o erro está dentro de uma função ele não interfere em outra. A forma como o AP perguntou é muito genérica... Dentro de um escopo único tudo que vier abaixo do erro normalmente não executa. Sem uma situação real é difícil dizer qq coisa, por isso deixei como comentário. O fato de ocorrer o erro em um lugar insolado dentro de uma função, pode não atrapalhar o restante do código, dependendo do caso logicamente... E nem entendo de JS, mas já vi muito código com erro "funcionando" rss

Comment: @hugocsl isso, eu também concordo com que você fez, não é sempre, não é regra, principalmente na caixinha de surpresa `Javascript`. A pergunta dele realmente é isso para de funcionar, mas, talvez (como o pessoal não faz uma pergunta melhor que engloba mais cenários) seja o seu exemplo um bom presságio em dizer que tudo depende. Importante o que você fez.

Comment: @hugocsl, era isso, funcionou! sem ter que precisar parar todo o código por causa de um erro, por favor será que tem como você adicionar uma resposta com mais detalhes?

Comment: @hugocsl, isso significa que se o erro estiver dentro do escopo da função `a()`, esse mesmo erro não vai afetar a função `b()` que está fora da função `a()`???

Comment: Draw o JS não eh minha especialidade, prefiro deixar que alguém com mais experiência responda para vc, isso se aparecer aqui alguém disposto... Talvez se vc fizer uma pergunta mais objetiva e com o seu problema real, com o código real do problema, alguém possa te ajudar de forma mais acertiva para o seu caso... Um erro na função a() não necessariamente vai bloquear b(), mas vc tem que expor sua situação real com seu código atual

Comment: Tá bom, mas muito obrigado por responder, isso abriu outro caminho para eu xeretar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neste contexto, no momento que há um erro no código não tem porque ele continuar executando, todo o resto está comprometido. Pode ser que alguns casos não esteja, mas é complicado avaliar isto, se deu erro sempre é tratado como impossível continuar, mesmo que depois dê para fazer adequadamente. Em tese poderia criar uma forma de avaliar isto e continuar, mas dá um trabalho monumental, fica lento e não traz vantagens práticas. Conserte o erro e seja feliz.

Conforme comentário acima há contexto que a execução não pára, porém o erro ainda existe. É JavaScript sendo JavaScript (inconsistência). Eu fiz testes em várias situações (dentro de escopo conforme o comentário) e em todas o código pára de executar, o hugocls mostrou um caso que pode ser considerado *corner case* que aceita continuar. A não ser que alguém apresente um *rationale* do comitê, ou algo na especificação dizendo que queriam isto, considero que ou é erro na especificação ou na implementação (muito comum até por JS ter uma das piores especificações já criadas dando margem pra muita interpretação do implementador - curiosamente em contraposição ao C que deixa o implementador ter muita flexibilidade sem ser vago ou ambíguo), inclusive indica ser isto porque não faz muito sentido não só continuar, como continuar em um caso tão específico.